# C# DllImport Attempted to read or write protected memory

Tags: c#, c++, dllimport

I'm trying to call a function from a C++ library using DllImport

```
[DllImport("DLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
private static extern IntPtr XXX(double dtoday, double dexp, double fwd, double[] sList, double[] vList);
```

The signature of the C++ function is

```
std::vector <double> XXX( const double dtoday,
                const double dexp,
                const double fwd,
                const std::vector <double> &sList,
                const std::vector <double> &vList)
```

The problem I'm having is that &sList and &vList are empty by the time they get to the C++ (dll), I think this is happening because of the & in the function definition.

I have tried `[In, Out] ref vList` in the import signature but that didn't solve the issue.

If anyone has any ideas they would be gratefully received

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the use of `std::vector <double>`. That's simply not possible with p/invoke. C++ classes cannot be used as p/invoke arguments.

You'll need to convert that to good old-fashioned arrays to make progress. The return value will need some special treatment too. The usual approach is to have the caller allocate the memory, and the callee populate it.

If you have a large number of such functions to call, then you might find that the burden of wrapping them all in p/invoke friendly functions is too tiresome. In which case C++/CLI is to be recommended. You'll be able to call the C++ code directly, and expose a .net interface using standard .net types.

Comment: Hi David, thank you for your response. I only have a couple of functions to call so it shouldn't take too long to wrap them as you suggest. I'll update if it works